# Returning pointer to the letter in string

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, masm, irvine32

This is my code to search ih some string consists of one letter:

```
selectedWords BYTE "BICYCLE"
inputLetter BYTE 'Y'

cld                                 
mov ecx, LENGTHOF selectedWords     
mov edi, offset selectedWords       
mov al, inputLetter                 ;Load character to find
repne scasb                         ;Search
jne notfound
```

But how to return the pointer to the letter in string?

If I want after to change one leter with some other. Its easy to do if you have pointer to the letter in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `repne scasb` finds the element, `EDI` points to the element **after** the first match. You have to decrement it to get the pointer to the desired element.

You don't need to clear the direction flag (`cld`). It's very very unlikelikely that the direction flag is set without any involvement of your part. And if so, you should seit it back to the former status.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
selectedWords BYTE "BICYCLE"
inputLetter BYTE 'Y'

err_msg BYTE "Not found.", 0

.CODE
main PROC

    mov ecx, LENGTHOF selectedWords
    mov edi, offset selectedWords
    mov al, inputLetter                 ; Load character to find
    repne scasb                         ; Search
    jne notfound

    dec edi
    mov al, [edi]
    call WriteChar                      ; Irvine32: Write a character in AL

    exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess

    notfound:
    lea edx, err_msg
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a null-terminated string pointed to by EDX
    exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess

main ENDP

END main
```

If you don't like `repne scasb` you can scan the word with a "normal" comparison loop

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
selectedWords BYTE "BICYCLE"
inputLetter BYTE 'Y'

err_msg BYTE "Not found.", 0

.CODE
main PROC

    mov edi, offset selectedWords
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF selectedWords
    mov al, inputLetter

    @@:
    cmp [edi], al                       ; Compare memory/immediate value
    je found                            ; JE = jump if equal
    inc edi                             ; Increment pointer
    dec ecx                             ; Decrement counter
    jne @B                              ; Jump back to the last @@, if ECX == 0

    jmp notfound

    found:
    mov al, [edi]
    call WriteChar                      ; Irvine32: Write a character in AL

    exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess

    notfound:
    lea edx, err_msg
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a null-terminated string pointed to by EDX
    exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess

main ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 2):

If you read the documentation for [`REP`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html) and  [`SCASB`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/SCAS:SCASB:SCASW:SCASD.html) you'll see that SCAS updates `edi`. Thus the location of the matching char is stored in `EDI`.
All you have to do is return `EDI` if `ZF=1` and return 0 if `ZF<>1`.

```
  cld                                 
  mov ecx, LENGTHOF selectedWords     
  mov edi, offset selectedWords       
  mov al, inputLetter                 ;Load character to find
  repne scasb                         ;Search
  jne notfound
found:
  mov eax,edi                   ;return the address of the match.
  ret
notfound:
  xor eax,eax                   ;return 0 aka not found as address.
  ret
```

Comment: I am making hangman game so I need to search the world if have some letter inside her..