# Change only one letter in string

Tags: arrays, string, assembly, masm, irvine32

I have 2 string and one letter.

```
selectedWords BYTE "BICYCLE"
guessWords BYTE "-------"
inputLetter BYTE 'C'
```

Base on [this answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44343780/returning-pointer-to-the-letter-in-string), I write code who compere if selectedWords have letter C and If this is the case he need to change string guessWords:

**guessWords "--C-C--"**

But from some strange reason I get all other possibilities, just not correct one. Some suggestions on how to solve this problem.

Comment: BTW, with hangman you can also use different approach, to have boolean array of alphabet size, to remember, which character was already guessed. Then when doing output of currently known word parts, you can go through the "selected word" letter by letter, and either output `'-'` or the letter itself, depending on the state of the alphabet boolean array. So you don't need "guess word" at all. And after such formatted output, you can keep counter of how many letter were displayed as `'-'`, so you can use that to decide if further letter has to be guessed, or the word is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, forget the so called string instructions (scas, comps, movs). Second, you need a fixed pointer (dispkacement) with an index, e.g `[esi+ebx]`. Have you considered that `WriteString` needs a null-terminated string?

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.DATA
selectedWords BYTE "BICYCLE"
guessWords BYTE SIZEOF selectedWords DUP ('-'), 0   ; With null-termination for WriteString
inputLetter BYTE 'C'

.CODE
main PROC

    mov esi, offset selectedWords       ; Source
    mov edi, offset guessWords          ; Destination
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF selectedWords     ; Number of bytes to check
    mov al, inputLetter                 ; Search for that character
    xor ebx, ebx                        ; Index EBX = 0

    ride_hard_loop:
    cmp [esi+ebx], al                   ; Compare memory/register
    jne @F                              ; Skip next line if no match
    mov [edi+ebx], al                   ; Hang 'em lower
    @@:
    inc ebx                             ; Increment pointer
    dec ecx                             ; Decrement counter
    jne ride_hard_loop                  ; Jump if ECX != 0

    mov edx, edi
    call WriteString                    ; Irvine32: Write a null-terminated string pointed to by EDX
    exit                                ; Irvine32: ExitProcess

main ENDP

END main
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. You solve all my main problem what I have in my project. When I finish project I would publish him on git, and write paper about that. So I desided to dedication my paper to you.. One big thank you.. :)

Comment: @SakaSerbia: Thanks, I feel honored. But you don't need to do that. Rather drink a big glass of Šljivovica to my health. :-)

Comment: I get maximum poens on my project. Thank you a lot. Here is code on git https://github.com/SakaSerbia/Hangman---Visual-Studio-2015-with-Irvine